# Ler vários ficheiros .txt e mostrar conteúdo - c++

Tags: c++

Preciso da vossa ajuda, tenho vários ficheiros .txt com texto e quero que o meu programa peça ao utilizador os nomes de ficheiros e armazene o conteúdo em memória e que em seguida mostre o conteúdo deles. Tenha feito algum código mas só consigo ver o conteúdo do primeiro ficheiro. Podem me ajudar?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    ifstream arquivoe; 
    string ficheiro[] = {""};
    string linha;
    char condicao='s';
    int tamanho = sizeof(ficheiro) / sizeof(string);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
    {

        while (condicao == 's' || condicao == 'S')
        {

            cout << ("Introduza o nome do ficheiro que deseja armazenar: ");
            cin >> ficheiro[i];
            arquivoe.open(ficheiro[i]); // abertura do .txt a partir do metodo.open.
            cout << ("Pretende continuar a armazenar ficheiros[S/N]? ");
            cin >> condicao;;
            system("CLS");
        }

    }
        
    if (arquivoe.is_open()) {

        while (getline(arquivoe, linha))

        {
            cout << linha << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << ("Não foi possivel abrir arquivo");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, mas acho que entendi.
tenta mudar essa linha:

```
    string ficheiro[10] = {}; //10 é o número de arquivos. Você pode alterar isso
```